# ASP.NET MVC: is it a good idea to return a File result from a byte[]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in one of my controllers which creates a downloadable zip file which should be served to the user. Currently my code looks something like this:

```
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
    // ... use SharpZipLib to write zip file content to the above MemoryStream ...
    return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", "file.zip");
}
```

I am wondering if it is a good idea go convert memoryStream to a `byte[]`, I guess this takes up more memory then using the stream? There is an overload to `File()` which takes a `Stream` object, and I passed in my memoryStream variable, but then just a blank page showed up.

Ideally I dont have to use a `FileStream` and write a file to disk.

Comment: Did you reset the position of the stream?

Comment: Perhaps you should make an estimation of the size before making the zip, and use file on disk instead if it's going to be large, to preserve memory. For a large file the network bandwidth will be the bottle neck, not the disk operation.

Comment: @Guffa: What would be a "sane" size in order to still use the MemoryStream? The app is running on a single server with 4 GB and I dont expect to high load and not a lot parallel downloads. Using a memory stream is a bit more easy for me as I dont have do to a cleanup on old zip files...

Comment: You can set your limit to perhaps something like 100 MB. You don't want it too be too large so that it's easy to overload the server by making a lot of requests. If you use a file as temporary storage you can remove it immediately after sending the data to the client, there is no need to keep it on the server for a while.

Comment: Thanks, 100 MB seems like a good choice! How would I go about deleting a larger temp file after it has been sent to the client? I mean, after returning my File result in the controller action, I dont have any more control over the stream? Or is there some kind of event that notifys me when the request is done?

Comment: Once you have written the data to the output stream, there is no use for the file, and you can delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the MemoryStream as a stream instead of getting the array elliminates copying all of the content at once. Reading the stream also involves copying, but that is in smaller chunks.

Set the position of the memory stream to the beginning before reading from it:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Comment: This still could take a lot of memory as the whole zip will be stored in the memory stream by SharpZipLib.

Comment: @Darin: Yes of course. That's why it's better to read it as a stream to elliminate another copy of all the data.

Answer (score 5):

If you really care about memory then here's a solution that will directly write to the response stream. First define your custom ActionResult:

```
public class SharpZipLibResult : FileResult
{
    private readonly string _fileDownloadName;
    private readonly string[] _filesToZip;
    private const int ChunkSize = 1024;

    public SharpZipLibResult(string fileDownloadName, params string[] filesToZip)
        : base("application/octet-stream")
    {
        _fileDownloadName = fileDownloadName;
        _filesToZip = filesToZip;
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        var cd = new ContentDisposition();
        cd.FileName = _fileDownloadName;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        response.BufferOutput = false;
        using (var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.OutputStream))
        {
            foreach (var file in _filesToZip)
            {
                var entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(file));
                zipStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                using (var reader = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] actual = new byte[bytesRead];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, actual, 0, bytesRead);
                        zipStream.Write(actual, 0, actual.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this technique you could serve some really huge zip files without caring about memory or having to clean some temporary zip files on your server hard drives.

And finally your controller action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new SharpZipLibResult(
        "result.zip", 
        @"c:\work\report1.pdf",
        @"c:\work\report2.pdf",
        @"c:\work\report3.pdf"
    );
}
```

Using this method memory footprint is minimized because the zip is written directly to the response stream which in terms will be represented by an underlying network socket.

Of course depending on where your files are stored the `SharpZipLibResult` could be tweaked. Here I assume the files are stored on the file system.

Comment: Consider response buffering also. There is little point in spending a lot of work writing directly to the response stream if it's all buffered in memory anyway...

Comment: Sure, but I thought that the OP was looking for a solution to minimize memory consumption by avoid buffering the whole zip in memory. In my example the whole zip is never loaded into memory. It is being created dynamically and written directly to the response stream in chunks of 1KB.